# How to access a Virtual Machine webserver from outside the network

Tags: virtual-machine, webserver, remote-access

I have installed a virtual machine for using an ERP through webserver.
I have configured the network as NAT.
All of my computers attached to the local network can access the webserver by typing the server's ip followed by the port. 192.168.8.1:8080

How would I access the webserver through Internet from outside the local network.

Comment: Much more information about your network would be needed.  Do you have a static IP? Also keep in mind that some ISPs block port 80 and 8080 unless you are using a business class service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by forwarding port 8080 on your router to the local lan address of your vm (192.168.8.1). You will need to know your wan (internet) ip address, which you can find from the router or (usually) by googling 'find my ip' from a computer on your lan. And don't leave this in place for a long period unless you know what you are doing and are confident your webserver is secure.

Answer (score 0):

If your firewall is Linux-based, you would do this:

```bsh
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d <your_public_ip> -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to <server_private_ip>
iptables -I FORWARD -d <server_private_ip>  -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

You can have different internal/external ports, too:

```bsh
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d <your_public_ip> -p tcp --dport 8888 -j DNAT --to <server_private_ip>:8080
iptables -I FORWARD -d <server_private_ip>  -p tcp --dport 8888 -j ACCEPT
```

Depending on your needs, the `FORWARD` rule may not be restrictive enough since it is open to the world.